# Something I'm misunderstanding about rand() % i?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
const int n = 5;
int A[n][n]; // value of each cell
int V[n][n]; // total value of each cell

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        V[i][j] = 0; // initialize total value of each cell equal to zero
        A[i][j] = rand() % 10; // set each cell's value equal to some number 0-9
        printf("%i ", A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0)
        {
            V[i][j] = A[i][j];
        }
        else if (i == 0)
        {
            V[i][j] = V[i][j - 1] + A[i][j];
        }
        else if (j == 0)
        {
            V[i][j] = V[i - 1][j] + A[i][j];
        }
        else
        {
            if (V[i][j - 1] > V[i - 1][j])
            {
                V[i][j] = V[i][j - 1] + A[i][j];
            }
            else
            {
                V[i][j] = V[i - 1][j] + A[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (V[i][j] < 10) printf(" %i ", V[i][j]);
        else printf("%i ", V[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

cin.get();
```

}

This outputs https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAa4L.png

What I don't understand is why V[0][2] outputs 12 when it should output V[0][1] + A[0][2], or 7+4.

Context:
At a garage sale one day, you stumble upon an old school video game. In this video game, your
character must take a journey along an n × n grid, collecting rewards along the way. Specifically,
there is an n × n matrix A with nonnegative entries, and your character collects a reward equal to
Aij if he visits the cell (i, j) of the grid. Your objective is to maximize the sum of rewards collected
by your character.
(a) [4 points]. The rules of level one of the game are as follows. Your character starts at the
top-left corner — i.e., cell (1, 1) — of the grid, and must travel to the the bottom-right corner —
i.e., cell (n, n) — in sequence of steps. At each step, your character is allowed to move either one
cell to the right or one cell down in the grid; stepping upwards, to the left, or diagonally is not
2
allowed. Show how to compute the optimal journey in O(n
2
) time.

Comment: `V[0][1] + A[0][2]` it's actually 8 + 4. So, 12 is correct. `A[0][1] + A[0][2]` would be 7 + 4.

Comment: Thank you. I'm retarded.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get that idea about `7+4`?

Your code clearly says that `V[0][2]` is `V[0][1] + A[2][2]`. But on previous iteration of your cycle `V[0][1]` was set to `V[0][0] + A[0][1]`. And on yet previous iteration of your cycle `V[0][0]` was set to `A[0][0]`.

So, `V[0][0]` is `1`. Which makes `V[0][1] = 1 + 7 = 8`. Which makes `V[0][2] = 8 + 4 = 12`.

Everything is as you implemented it.